# Is this xkcd sentence grammatically correct?

Tags: grammar

So I saw [this xkcd](http://xkcd.com/1075/), and when I tried reading it, I always felt like the ending was a bit... unbalanced.

It says:

> You're in a box on wheels hurtling along several times faster than evolution could possibly have prepared you to go. (Next 5 miles.)

I can't figure out what's wrong with it, though... it's as if some word (e.g. "at"?) was supposed to follow the word "go".

So I was wondering, is the sentence grammatically correct, or is it indeed missing something?
If so, what?

Comment: The sentence is gramatically fine and, moreover, is exactly suited to the feeling its author wishes to express. If you remove or change a word — imperfection ensues.

Comment: So what's wrong with ending a sentence with an infinitive? It seems far more fluent than OP starting his first sentence in this post with the word **so**. Is it just me? I find that a really inappropriate way to introduce a question on ELU. It sounds like a stand-up comedian's opening line.

Comment: The grammar is perfect.  One thing that you COULD add is a comma after "wheels", but it doesn't really need it.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: I wasn't trying to criticize the xkcd (heck, it's not even *supposed* to be grammatically correct); I was just asking a grammar question... no need to get annoyed.

Comment: @Mehrdad: I'm not annoyed. But you've asked quite a few good questions here, so I assume you're keen to improve your English. That (in the preceding sentence) was a reasonable context in which to use the word *"so"*. The opening paragraph of your question definitely isn't, and many people would say neither is the final paragraph (you won't learn anything like that by studying xkcd, but such knowledge is freely available here on ELU! :)

Comment: @Fumblefingers - the practice of starting a sentence with 'so' is now so common I wonder if it is beginning to take on the properties of something similar to the Latin vocative case?

Comment: @Jascol: For *historical* reasons, grammarians are always trying to shoehorn current English into the categorization systems overtly manifested by Latin syntax / grammar, but personally I'd say this use of ***so*** qualifies as a "discourse marker". My problem is that although I often (over-)use words like ***well*** and ***anyway*** this way myself, it just doesn't feel quite right when there's no preceding context. ***So*** when it's the *first word* in a discourse (as in OP's case) I'm always left wondering "what possible context can ***so*** refer back to?"

Comment: @Fumblefingers Absolutely it's not necessarily correct to shoehorn into Latin grammar, but here I believe the similarity is remarkable. I agree broadly with what you are saying, but a discourse marker (correct me if I'm wrong) is usually used for signalling a new direction in an existing discourse rather than 'starting' one, as is the case here.

Comment: @Jascol: I certainly can't "correct you" for being wrong. I'm not sure that discourse markers are ***usually** used for signalling a new direction in an existing discourse* (they're very often used simply to "play for time" while the speaker is considering exactly how to phrase what he's about to say, for example). But without a doubt, the specific context is exactly the one we're considering here, and your words express it very well. I wish I'd thought of your exact phrasing myself.

Comment: @user16269 - I must admit, it bothers me that there's no comma there.

Answer (score 52, accepted):

It's perfectly fine. Let's rewrite it to see what's going on.

Original:

> You're in a box on wheels hurtling along several times faster than evolution could possibly have prepared you to go.

"box on wheels" => "car"
"hurtling along" => "going"

Creates:

> You're in a car going several times faster than evolution could possibly have prepared you to go.

Now we can erase this unnecessary part:

> You're in a car going <strike>several times</strike> faster than evolution could possibly have prepared you to go.

Finally creating:

> You're in a car going faster than evolution could possibly have prepared you to go.

If you want to go even further, you can simplify all this to:

> You're going faster than you are prepared to go.

Seems all fine here!

Comment: Two more steps: *You are going faster than you should*, and *Slow down!*

Comment: very good, +1. As has been said on these boards by those more sage than I, "grammar isn't about strings of words, it's about constructions and their constituents".

Comment: Hmm. *"You're going faster than you are prepared to go"* would normally be interpreted as meaning *"...faster than you are **willing** to go"*. A more fluent version is *"You're going faster than you're **designed** to [go]"* (most speakers would omit that final *go*).

Comment: So basically, it was 'You're going faster than you're prepared to go', and OP thought it said, 'You're going at a higher speed than you are prepared to go _at_.'

Comment: Guys, guys, carefully here! I'm not claiming my final sentence makes the exactly same sense as the original! I just simplified it as much as possible, whilst keeping the original syntax.

Comment: @FumbleFingers except that designed implies a designer, which might not sit well with some of the xkcd audience.

Comment: @cms_mgr: The blind watchmaker strikes again! By that token, *natural selection* implies a *selector*. Personally, I have no problem saying a rabbit's eyes are designed for all-round vision, even if in practice it only came about because foxes ate all the rabbits whose genetic makeup didn't give them that extra edge. But that's just because I can only get my head around the "conscious higher power" concept if I assume we're in a computer simulation where the programming team might seem like "God" to us (if they ever intervened after "run program", which seems not to be the case).

Comment: @FumbleFingers isn't the *natural* in *natural selection* removing the implication of any selector other than nature?

Comment: @cms_mgr: It really depends on how you define "nature" (which a pantheist might capitalise). That's not to mention more figurative usages where your range of options includes a "natural choice" which you might or might not opt for.

Answer (score 5):

I think it would be better phrased as:

> You're in a box on wheels hurtling along several times faster than evolution **could have possibly** prepared you to go. (Next 5 miles.)

Comment: Personally, I disagree.  "could possibly have" clearly sets the emphasis on "prepared you to go".  "could have possibly prepared" muddles the "possibly" and the punchline.  I therefore prefer the original.

Answer (score 0):

The sentence is perfectly fine. However, what may be throwing you off is the change of verbs.

Let's break down the sentence (*similarly* to how @RiMMER has):

Original:

> You're in a box on wheels hurtling along several times faster than evolution could possibly have prepared you to go.

Changing "box on wheels" to "car" and removing unnecessary parts.

Creates:

> You're in a car hurtling along faster than evolution could possibly have prepared you to go.

and finally, if we go even further, we can simplify all this to:

> You're hurtling along faster than you are prepared to go.

In the sentence, we first refer to the movement as hurtling, and then refer to it as going. There is a change of verb! However, because the two verbs are used to represent the same action, this is not an error.

---

In order to avoid this verb change the original sentence would have had to have been:

> You're in a box on wheels hurtling along several times faster than evolution could possibly have prepared you to hurtle along.

or

> You're in a box on wheels hurtling along several times faster than evolution could possibly have prepared you to.

Note that this sentence ends with a preposition, which is, for whatever reason, undesirable to some (although not necessarily wrong according to [Oxford Dictionaries](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/words/ending-sentences-with-prepositions) and [Merriam-Webster online](http://www.merriam-webster.com/video/0025-preposition.html))

Finally, if you don't want to end with a preposition:

> You're in a box on wheels hurtling along at a speed that is several times faster than that for which evolution could possibly have prepared you.